# Problem in installing BBC Micro emulator in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: make, configure

I have download the BBC Micro emulator from [here](http://b-em.bbcmicro.com/B-emv2.0aLinux.tar.gz).

I un-tar it in a folder "BBC" under home directory. Tthen open terminal and chage to directory BBC, and use `./configure`.
After that I type `make`. It gives:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/drsayandas/BBC/src'
source='32016.c' object='b_em-32016.o' libtool=no \
DEPDIR=.deps depmode=none /bin/bash ../depcomp \
gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME="B-em" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME="b-em" -DPACKAGE_VERSION="2.2" -DPACKAGE_STRING="B-em\ 2.2" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT="Tom\ Walker\ \<b-em@bbcmicro.com\>" -DPACKAGE_URL="" -DPACKAGE="b-em" -DVERSION="2.2" -DHAVE_LIBZ=1 -DHAVE_LIBOPENAL=1 -DHAVE_LIBALUT=1 -I. -I/usr/include -g -O2 -O3 -c -o b_em-32016.o `test -f '32016.c' || echo './'`32016.c
/bin/bash: ../depcomp: No such file or directory
Makefile:372: recipe for target 'b_em-32016.o' failed
make[1]: *** [b_em-32016.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/drsayandas/BBC/src'
Makefile:236: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

What can I do? I have installed `g++`

Comment: The tar archive appears to contain *links* to files it expects to find in system directory `/usr/share/automake-1.11` - it might work if you install the `automake1.11` package (although please carefully review any potential conflicts with an existing automake package before going ahead).

Comment: @steeldriver could you post an answer please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably need liballegro4 for allegro-config to show up, it's been changed in latest but B-em doesn't seem to know it

`sudo apt install liballegro4-dev`

#You need to install the ALUT library.

`sudo apt install libalut-dev`

`sudo apt-get install automake1.11`

fixed this  `../depcomp: No such file or directory error for me and let my make actually build B-em on my pi4 Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (deb 10.8)`